# GW Code Categories || Nested || 2 Category Groups

Tags: categories, gwcode-categories

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my head around this issue and I'm probably over thinking it as well as just have spent too much time "in" it :) So i'm hoping someone can straighten this out for me.

I have a Business channel with 2 Category Groups: State/City (category id = 9) and Businesses (category id = 11).

State/City should be self-explanatory as those have a State for the Parent and City for Children.

Businesses has this setup (some Categories have children some don't):

[image]
So some entries are in Colorado and Denver BUT also in Bars > Dive

I need to start on the State level, then to the City, then to the Category then a Sub-category if there is one. IF not then I just want to show the listings in those categories.

I've been working on this for a while and haven't had any luck with it. I always seem to get "close" then at the end I don't have the listings showing by City/State AND the Business type that it is.

Without writing a ton of `{if segment_5 !='' AND segment_6 ==''} etc...` I'm not sure how to drill down to the listings.

So I'm hoping there are people out there that can help me "un-complicate" this as this SHOULD work but I'm probably missing something.

Thanks for the help comrades!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on what you want your output to be, but check out the functionality of [Low Seg2Cat](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat) and/or [Category Sorted Entries](http://rog.ee/category_sorted_entries) to see if either can be helpful...

Comment: The output is simple. I have hundreds of businesses entered. Some are in Boulder, CO...some in Denver. They are listed in Categories (City/State and Businesses). I just want these organied: By State > City > Business Type > Sub-Business Type if there are additional categories, then finally a listing page with the appropriate Categories (City/State AND Business Category) does that help?

Comment: "I just want these organied: By State > City > Business Type > Sub-Business Type" are each of these pages or is this all on one screen?  If these are each pages, I think Solspace Super Search might be useful - you wouldn't be thinking in terms of URL segments, but rather constructing category queries.